# selecting by mouse clicks instead of press-drag action in MFC

Tags: select, mfc, mouse

I am quite new to MFC. I am currently using the CrectTracker class of MFC to draw a selection rectangle to select an area on a graphic in MFC based application. However, I would like to do the selection using mouse clicks instead of L button press and drag and release action.

Can somebody point me to an example where the crectracker class can be used to select an area using mouse clicks, first click to start the selection and second to end? Or do I have to implement my own OnLButtonUp actions for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the MouseMove event.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3158baat%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

This functions gives you 2 Parameters.

1. Flag : Here you can check the Left Mouse Button is Clicked
2. Point : Position of the Mouse cursor.